# TextView[][] array is crashing app, why?

Tags: android, arrays, textview, multidimensional-array

I want to use an Array of TextView arrays. The app crashes when I try to set the text of every TextView, in every TextView array (the nested 'for' loop in the code). Here is my code:

```
package com.example.whynotworking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView[] FirstArray;
TextView[] SecondArray;
TextView[] ThirdArray;

int SizeOfTextViewArrays;

TextView[][] TheArrayArray = {FirstArray,SecondArray,ThirdArray};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("DebugTAG", "no problems yet");

    SizeOfTextViewArrays = 5;

    FirstArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];
    SecondArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];
    ThirdArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];

    Log.d("DebugTAG", "still no problems");

    taskIwantToDo();
}

public void taskIwantToDo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < TheArrayArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SizeOfTextViewArrays; j++) {
        Log.d("DebugTAG", "I see this log come up once");
        TheArrayArray[i][j].setText("Text to set...");
        Log.d("DebugTAG", "But I don't see this one...");
    }
    }
}
}
```

I think that part of the issue is the TextView[][] array being declared and initiated outside of the onCreate() method. But when I try to initiate it inside onCreate(), it (eclipse IDE) tells me "Array constants can only be used in initializers"...

The LogCat output is:

07-05 21:08:20.346: D/DebugTAG(340): no problems yet
07-05 21:08:20.346: D/DebugTAG(340): still no problems
07-05 21:08:20.346: D/DebugTAG(340): I see this log come up once

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create the contents of your arrays:

```
public void taskIwantToDo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < TheArrayArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SizeOfTextViewArrays; j++) {
            TheArrayArray[i][j] = new TextView(this); // <-- THIS LINE
            TheArrayArray[i][j].setText("Text to set...");
        }
    }
}
```

before that however you need to create your arrays properly. either do it all at module-level:

```
int SizeOfTextViewArrays = 5;

TextView[] FirstArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];
TextView[] SecondArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];
TextView[] ThirdArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];

TextView[][] TheArrayArray = {FirstArray,SecondArray,ThirdArray};
```

or do it all in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("DebugTAG", "no problems yet");

    SizeOfTextViewArrays = 5;

    FirstArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];
    SecondArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];
    ThirdArray = new TextView[SizeOfTextViewArrays];

    TheArrayArray = {FirstArray,SecondArray,ThirdArray};
```

Comment: The app still crashes - this time it crashes at the new line of suggested code.

Comment: when you set up `TheArrayArray`, `FirstArray`, `SecondArray`, and `ThirdArray` are still null. you need to set everything up in the correct order. updated with examples.

Comment: please remember to upvote/accept if this solves your problem.

Comment: That did the trick. I needed to declare and initiate the single arrays before the double array which holds them. Thank you.